# How to preview my custom image file type as thumbnail in Windows File Explorer?

Tags: windows, registry, thumbnails, file-extension, windows-explorer

I need to add my own custom file-extension **.myext** to the Windows system file-types which are automatically previewed in Windows File Explorer as images in the Thumbnail view (like any other image types e.g. `.png`).

**PLEASE NOTE:** **.myext** files are obtained by simply RENAMING the extension of an existing **.png** file from `.png` to `.myext` (which should make it unnecessary to implement my own custom thumbnail handler).

So I tried the following: in the Windows Registry key `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\KindMap` I added this value: `.myext REG_SZ picture`. Then I rebooted Windows. But the `.myext` files are still not viewed as image in Windows File Explorer's Thumbnails view.

So how can I preview `.myext` files (which as I said are renamed `.png` files) in Windows File Explorer's Thumbnails view?